# atom <script> snippet, one line

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

I would like the atom script snippet when I type "script" followed by TAB to be one line instead of as now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

I am not sure how to add such a custom snippet to the cson file. I also tried to find the original snippet for it under %LocalPackage% but not sure where it is.

Thanks in advance ☕

Comment: Well, I sort of managed to work around this by installing the autoclose-html package and adding the tags I want to force inline there. Still, I wonder if the script snippet can be forced inline too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your `snippets.cson` file:

```
'.text.html.basic':

  'script (one line)':
    'prefix': 'script'
    'body': '<script${1: type="${2:text/javascript}"}>$3</script>'
```

The snippet has the same tab stops / general behavior as the multi-line `script` snippet it's overriding. Feel free to customize.